# with access vba resize an excel chart that is placed in word document

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-word

Due to company rules I have to create a word document from access and I need excel charts in it.

I can already export the required charts to the right place in the word document, but am now stuck in resizing it. I basically can't find the chart :-(

So far I have this:

```
With xlSheet
    Set xlSheet = .Application.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .ChartObjects(1).Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=1, Size:=1, Format:=-4147
End With

with wdDoc
    .Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=3, _
        Placement:=0, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With
```

xlSheet is a worksheet and wdDoc a Document. The Pasting is good, but I have no real clue how to find the chart. I tried

```
Dim thisChart as Object
With xlSheet
    Set xlSheet = .Application.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .ChartObjects(1).Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=1, Size:=1, Format:=-4147
End With

with wdDoc
    .Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=3, _
        Placement:=0, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    Set thisChart = .Selection.ShapeRange(1)
End With
```

But I get the error `invalid Argument or Procedure`

Thanks for help,

kaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an InlineShape object. A collection of InlineShapes can be accessed at the document level. So what I was searching for was:

```
wdDoc.InlineShapes(Index)
```